How to calculate abcd fitting coefficients?
In the Matlab I have the following equation, which gives me a, b, c and d coefficients.
gaussEqn = 'a*exp(-((x-b)/c)^2)+d';

[fittedModel, gof] = fit(sensData(:, 1), sensData(:, 2), gaussEqn, 'Start', startPoints);
a = fittedModel.a;
b = fittedModel.b;
c = fittedModel.c;
d = fittedModel.d;

How can I do the same in C# using math libraries? The equation is not exactly gaussian, but contains an extra d coefficient. But I will be happy even to calculate a, b c only based on gaussian equation.

Why use a c# library?  Create a mathlab dll and then call the dll from a c# application.

@jdweng. Do I need then to install Matlab or any components on target machine? Could you point me to some example as this is also very interesting approach and will make my life super easy.

The runtime version of Matlab that was used to compile the dll which is free.  I do it from Matlab menu.  You can find samples by searching web.  In c# you use Import dll to run code.

@wohlstad : The runtime version of Matlab is free.

@jdweng are you sure the required matlab runtime is free ? If I remember correctly it is not, but I might be wrong.

@wohlstad : YES.  You need a license to compile the script, but running can be done for free.

"MATLAB® Runtime contains the libraries needed to run compiled MATLAB applications on a target system without a licensed copy of MATLAB."

@jdweng After some research it doesn't look like I can produce dll files in the MATLAB by default. I need Compiler SDK which cost a fortune.

I have used Math.Net for this in the past. It's free and has some great stuff.

@FelixCastor I checked possible functions in that library before posting question, but couldn't find the ones to calculate a, b, c and d

@Pablo : It depends on your license.  If you are a student you may be able to get a teacher to compile the code.

@Pablo It's part of the regression functions Math.Numerics.Regression

If you want to use MathNet to estimate the fit parameters in C#, as per Felix Castor's recommendation, you may use
Fit.Curve
functions.
Using your model function, in order to test the fit, I started with some arbitrary parameters a0 = 2.1, b0 = 3.4, c0 = 1.35, d0 = 5.3. I generated n = 1000
equidistant x values and computed the function for them. I added some
normally distributed random noise to the y values and used matlab's
fit to retrieve the parameters (which are typically close to the
"correct" values, a0, b0, c0, d0 if the initial guess is sufficiently
close).
I ended up with this matlab code:
a0 = 2.1; b0 = 3.4; c0 = 1.35; d0 = 5.3;
n = 1000;
x = linspace(0, 2*b, n);
y = a0 * exp(-((x - b0) / c0).^2) + d0 + randn(1, n)*0.05;

startPoints = [2, 2, 1, 1];
fittedModel = fit(x', y', 'a*exp(-((x-b)/c)^2)+d', 'Start', startPoints);
a = fittedModel.a;
b = fittedModel.b;
c = fittedModel.c;
d = fittedModel.d;

fprintf("a = %f   b = %f   c = %f   d = %f", a, b, c, d);

which I wrote in order to show its C# MathNet "translation":
using MathNet.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;

double F0(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x)
{
    return a * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow((x - b) / c, 2)) + d;
}

const int n = 1000;
const double a0 = 2.1, b0 = 3.4, c0 = 1.35, d0 = 5.3; // "correct" parameters

var x = Generate.LinearSpaced(n, 0, 2*b0);
var rnd = new double[n];
Normal.Samples(rnd, 0.0, 1.0);
var y0 = Generate.Map(x, xi=>F0(a0, b0, c0, d0, xi));
var y = Generate.Map2(y0, rnd, (yi, ri) => yi + ri * 0.05);

var (a, b, c, d) = Fit.Curve(x, y, F0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0);
Console.WriteLine($"a = {a} b = {b}  c = {c}  d = {d}");

That being said, you have to be aware that MathNet's algorithms are different
from those of matlab, with matlab's versions being more sophisticated and
more likely to find the right solution in difficult/edge cases.
